# difference quotient estimate $\|\Delta^h_{v }u\|_{p,V} \le C'\|Du\|_{p,U}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ where $U$ is open in $\Bbb{R}^n$ define difference quotient be the one
$$\Delta_v^hu = \frac{u(x+ hv) - u(x)}{h}$$
(where $v$ is some unit length direction vector)

Then we have taking $V\subset\subset U$ with $|h|<\text{dist}(\partial U,V)$.
Then we have the following estimate :

$$\|\Delta^h_{e_i }u\|_{p,V} \le C\|\partial_iu\|_{p,U}$$

How to derive the case for any direction? that is the following relation based on the above result?

$$\|\Delta^h_{v }u\|_{p,V} \le C'\|Du\|_{p,U}$$

I try to make it clear but fails.I have one idea taking rotation transformation to anyother coordinate that $v$ is unit vector in that coordinate the trasformation for example rotation is global smooth hence it may be valid to do like this

(In Evans' PDE book only prove the case for $D^hu = (D^h_1 u ,...,D^h_n u)$ not the specific directional quotient as I asked here)